# Installing Anaconda on Ubuntu 13.10 giving an error message

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, anaconda

I ran the installer of Anaconda and at the end I got this message:

```
...
installing: zlib-1.2.7-0 ...
installing: anaconda-1.9.1-np18py27_0 ...
installing: _cache-0.0-x0 ...
Anaconda-1.9.1-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 389: /home/ohm/anaconda/pkgs/python-2.7.6-1/bin/python: cannot execute binary file
ERROR:
cannot execute native linux-64 binary, output from 'uname -a' is:
Linux ohm-ThinkCentre-M57 3.11.0-17-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 21:53:31 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
ohm@ohm-ThinkCentre-M57:~/Downloads$
```

When I try to import one of the modules, like scipy, it doesn't let me..
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to download the 32 bit version of anaconda. You should be able to get it from the [downloads](http://continuum.io/downloads) page.

Answer (score 1):

This error message means Linux doesn't recognize the file as a shell script or as an executable file.

Typically the cause is running an executable on the wrong architecture - if you try to run x86 executables on an ARM CPU, this message comes up.